# Using a Model Variable in another Model that is related

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, class-constants

I'm currently trying to run variables that are declared in a model in a function for checking and creating an email user.

The issue I'm having is that the variables being declared in model A.

```
const USERNAME = ':email_username';
const PASSWORD = ':email_password';
```

Do not work when I call them in Model B such as

```
 $email_user = SystemEmail::USERNAME;
        //$email_user ="NewtestRemail";
        //$email_password = "PDmfSqR520eH";
  $email_password = SystemEmail::PASSWORD;
```

I have also tried SystemEmail::model()->email_username;

But had no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that this SystemEmail is loaded (with the same Namespace) .. 
If its the same class its not possible that you can't access the constants..

Comment: Model A is Class SystemEmail, Model B is Class System

Comment: `"Do not work"` is too vague a problem - please describe exactly whats wrong - are you getting error messages?

Comment: Because I'm using the cpanel API (through a class file, nothing on error logs) I'm not getting feedback. If I use the first way using SystemEmail:USERNAME there is no error message but it doesn't recognise the input. Any other way it says it does not recognise or the variable is not valid.

Comment: show all your SystemMail model please and also al the code when you recall this constant..not only few line ..